# MATLAB: Why is the envelope not showing? single double column vector error variable not found etc

Tags: matlab, datatable, envelope

I programmed this:

```matlab
%create Envelope of a signal
%________________________________

%load('y-data')
load('ungedaempft.mat','t','s');
envelope(ungedaempft,17,'peak');
```

**datatypes (all imported in workspace):**
.mat file: 400x2 table
variables `s` and `t`: 400x1 double (imported as column vector in workspace)
`t` = x-axis value
`s` = y-axis value

[that's how the .mat 400x2 table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PVT8.png)

**error message:**

> Warning: Variable 't' not found.
> In newenvelope (line 2)
> Warning: Variable 's' not found.
> In newenvelope (line 2)
> Error using envelope
> Expected input to be one of these types:
> single, double
> Instead its type was table.
> Error in newenvelope (line 4)
> envelope(ungedaempft,17,'peak');

Tried to put the variables in ’s’ & in "s“ or in {s,t} form but nothing works. Obviously s & t are doubles so I don't see a problem & t & s are imported & exist & work. Rest of the errors have no specification what's wrong.

Documentation example:

> load('mtlb')
>
> envelope(mtlb,30,'peak')

Comment: What is the variable `ungedaempft`? It looks like your MAT-file doesn’t contain any variable called `s` or `t`, hence the warnings.

Comment: Thank you Cris for replying! For me it seems that s& t are already defined. I added a link for the look of the ungedaempft-table so that you can see it. Would be grateful hearing back from you

Comment: So `ungedaempft` is a `table` object with two columns called “s” and “t”. But `envelope` requires a 1D array as input, not a table. Maybe try `envelope(ungedaempft.s,17,'peak')`?

Comment: OMGGGGGGGG it worked!!! thank you infinitely!!! been desperately trying to figure this out for 3 weeks